# Should Tensorflow always be using the most Cuda cores it can?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm training a model right now and it's using almost all my VRAM but my CUDA usage is hovering between 10-20%. Is this normal? I know it's meant to use a lot of VRAM but I'm surprised it's not using a lot of Cuda cores.

[image: gpu details in task manager]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default tensorflow will allocate almost all GPU's VRAM, to limit that see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu?hl=en#limiting_gpu_memory_growth).

The GPU usage instead depends on the *batch size* (larger tends to utilize more GPU), *size of the neural network* (smaller models use less resource), *layer kind* (e.g. convolutions use the GPU more efficiently), and the *data pipeline*: if the way you move data from disk/RAM to GPU is a bottleneck, the GPU will wait for the new batch instead of doing processing.

Comment: It started to use more Cuda cores when I increased my batch size, though I was clearly being bottlenecked as I had fluctuating usage, though that seemed to be the root of the problem. Thanks!